# JavaScript `this` examples from MDN and books not working ... why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, this

I'm trying to understand JS `this` because it has been too confusing to me for too long, and no one has given me an explanation I can comprehend so far.  I went to MDN and tried a simple code example from their documentation.  The code straight copied from their page is as follows (console logs are my only addition):

```
var obj = {a: 'Custom'}
var a = 'Global'
function whatsThis () {
    return this.a
}

console.log(whatsThis())
console.log(whatsThis.call(obj))
console.log(whatsThis.apply(obj))
```

According to MDN, the output should be:

```
Global
Custom
Custom
```

Instead, I get

```
undefined
Custom
Custom
```

Incredulous, I tried an example from the somewhat-famous [You Don't Know JS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/1st-ed/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md) series, chapter 2 of book 2, regarding `this`.  I tried the following example, verbatim:

```
function foo() {
    console.log( this.a );
}

var a = 2;

foo();
```

The book says the output should be `2`, but I get `undefined`.

This is exactly why I want to learn more about `this`, but even books and MDN straight code examples are failing for me, making it very difficult to get my mind wrapped around a core concept of JS.  Please help me set this straight in my head.

Comment: Where are you running this code?

Comment: Copy/pasting the code you posted into the browser's console gives me Global, Custom, Custom, 2. There's nothing wrong with the MDN examples.

Comment: I was running these bare examples using Node.js from the command line.  I suppose the question I need to ask is, why does `this` work differently in Node than it does in the browser?

Answer (score 2):

Variables declared with `var` in a Node.js module don’t end up on the global object – modules have their own scope. You can put the properties you want to read on the global object explicitly:

```
global.a = 'Global';
```

```
global.a = 2;
```

(In browsers, it’s `window` instead of `global`, or you can use the [new](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_builtins_globalthis) portable `globalThis` for both.)

However, you won’t need to worry about this behaviour too much. In [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), which you should always use (and which will be applied automatically inside new features like classes and ES modules), the `this` of a plain function call like `whatsThis()` is just `undefined`.

```js
'use strict';

function whatsThis() {
  console.log('this is ' + this);
}

let obj = {
  whatsThis,
};

whatsThis();
whatsThis.call('a string');
obj.whatsThis();
```

The global object in Node should essentially never be used, and declaring variables with `var` at the top level in browser scripts is similarly bad practice.

Comment: If `this` is meaningless at global scope, and the `this` of a plain function call is `undefined` by design in strict mode (which we should be using), am I to understand that we should avoid using `this`?  What is its usefulness if we must contrive it with `call`/`bind`/`apply`?  Unfortunately I am getting more confused instead of less.

Comment: @Steverino: `this` is for methods and constructors. You’ll use it with classes a lot in modern JS, occasionally with non-class method calls, and rarely with a few other niche cases. Definitely not at the top level or with global function calls, though (although it’s still good to learn what these do at some point so you can read code using it).